# Rolling a die a maximum of two times, what is the expected sum of values?

Tags: probability, expected-value

You start out with $n$ dollars.
You roll a die twice, and get paid the number of dots on each toss. However, if you toss a 6 on the first toss, the game terminates and you lose all your money and don't accumulate any money from the toss. If you toss any of $1,2,\ldots,5$ on the first toss and then a 6 on the second toss, you don't accumulate value for either toss and you lose all your money, i.e., you end up with zero dollars ( remember you started out with $n$ dollars).

So here's some examples:

a) suppose we toss a 1 then a 6. We end the game with zero dollars. More generally, suppose with roll any of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and then a $6$, we will end the game with zero dollars.

b) suppose we toss a 2 then a 3. We end the game with n + 2 + 3 dollars. More generally, suppose we roll $a,b$ such that $a,b \in \{1,2,3,4,5\} $, then we end the game with $n + a + b$ dollars.

c) suppose we toss a 6. The game ends without a second toss and we end the game with zero dollars.

So while there are $36$ possible pairs, only $25$ of them accumulate value. What is the expected amount of money you have after this game? Note that I'm not asking for expected payoff, but the expected amount of money we have remaining given that we start out with $n$ dollars.

I believe the answer should be
$$
\frac{25}{36}n + \frac{1}{36}\left[ 10 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) \right] = \frac{25}{36}n + 4\frac{1}{6}
$$

I approached this problem in a  different way, and I'm getting a slightly different answer.
Suppose we have $x$ dollars, and we toss once. What is the expected amount of money we have after 1 toss?

$$
\frac{5}{6}x + \frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5) = \frac{5}{6}x + 2.5 \ \ \ \ (1)
$$

We plug in $x = n$, and we have
$$
\frac{5}{6}n + 2.5
$$

This is the expected amount of money we have after 1 round. Now if we plug this in for $x$ in equation (1), shouldn't we get the expected amount of money after 2 rounds?

Which would end up being
$$
\frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}n + 2.5 \right) + 2.5 \\
= \frac{25}{36}n + 4\frac{7}{12}
$$

Monte carlo matches my first approach. Assuming I didn't botch MC, what is wrong with the second approach?

Comment: "Dice" is plural.  The singular of "dice" is "die".  When you write "you lose all your money", doesn't this mean my outcome is $-n$ dollars?

Comment: @EricTowers You start out with $n$ dollars. You want the expected amount of money you have left over after the game.

Comment: So ... In the situation "If you toss any of 1,2,…,5 on the first toss and then a 6 on the second toss, you don't accumulate value for either toss and you lose all your money.", I lose $n$ dollars.  That is, my outcome is $-n$ dollars?

Comment: @EricTowers I guess, but I don't see how that's relevant if you're looking for expected amount of money you have left over and not the expected payoff.

Comment: Since $-n$ is a payoff, there should be a (large, negative) term corresponding to this loss of all the money.  Alternatively, there could be an imprecision in the statement of the problem and the intention was only that the payout is $0$, not $-n$.

Comment: @EricTowers The way I look at it is, you start out with $n$ dollars. If you roll a $6$ on either of the tosses, you end up with $0$ dollars. And that's the outcome. If you roll a $1$ on both tosses, then you end up with $n + 2$ dollars, etc..

Comment: Then in $11$ cases, you should have $-n$ as the payout in your expectation calculation.  Where is this negative payout in any of your calculations?  Or there should be $11$ cases with "0" money as the post-game result.  Where are those in your calculations?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm not computing the expected payout. I'm computing the expected amount of money that I have left over after the game is played. Those are different quantities

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, I also am unsure what the effect is of rolling a $(6)$.  However, whenever you roll something other than a $(6)$, your expected roll is $(3)$, which is the average value from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$

Therefore, with probability $\frac{25}{36}$, your net profit is $(2 \times 3).$

As discussed in the comments, I don't know what happens in the $(11/36)$ of the time that you roll at least one $(6)$.  That is, what does *lose all your money* signify, exactly?

Comment: In the $11/36$ time, you end up with zero dollars and using your "profit" terminology, your net profit would be $-n$ dollars. But we're asking for the expected amount of money remaining after the game, and not the expected profit.

Comment: Your expected profit matches the $4 \frac{1}{6}$ I have in the first approach, but I still don't see why the second approach is wrong.

Comment: I added a few examples in address your last question.

Comment: @David Good question.  I am unfamiliar with monte carlo methods, so your 2nd approach confuses me.  Outside of knowing that it has to be wrong, because your first approach (and my answer) have to be right, I can't dissect the flaw.  Perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the second toss *happens* *depends* on the result of the first toss. Hence you cannot break the problem into two independent subproblems and the second approach is wrong. The first approach is indeed correct, though.

Comment: When I expanded out some terms in the second approach, I saw that each number in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ was showing up 11 times, whereas in the first approach it was only showing up 10 times. So $10*(1+2+3+4+5) = 10*15 = 150$, and $11*(1+2+3+4+5) = 165$. $150/36 = 4\frac{1}{6}$ and $165/36 = 4\frac{7}{12}$. Why does breaking it down into two independent subproblems result in an additional count for each value?

Comment: Also, I think I'm a bit confused on how the second approach is breaking the problems into two *independent* subproblems. Isn't there still dependency, because I plug in the value for the first round into the recursive equation, and that inherently accounts for the situation where we roll a 6 on the first toss, and hence we wouldn't have a second toss to begin with?

Comment: @DAVID When you iterate the formula for expected value after one roll, you are assuming that the second roll is independent of the first (otherwise you would not be able to make such a simplification in the first place). In such a situation, $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ does hold, but this is not the situation.